# How to apply Taylor Series of e when exponent is a derivative operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following paragraph is a question:

$e^{\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)} = 1 + \frac{d}{dx} + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2 + \cdots$ is a sum of higher and higher derivatives.  Applying this series to $f(x)$ at $x = 0$ would give $f + f' + \frac{1}{2}f'' + \cdots$ at $x = 0$.  The Taylor series says: This is equal to $f(x)$ at $x = $ ____.

To put this in context: I'm an autodidact trying to work my way through Gilbert Strang's book \emph{Differential Equations and Linear Algebra} and came across this question.  I guess I'm not sure how we are applying this series to some function $f(x)$.  My thought is as follows:

For some function $f(x)$ I apply the series as follows: 
$e^{\left(\frac{d}{dx}f\right)} = 1 + \frac{d}{dx}f + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2f + \cdots$; however, this seems trivial as this just remains the same: $1 + f + \frac{1}{2}f'' + \frac{1}{3!}f''' + \cdots$ and is not anywhere near what the solutions manual has in mind.

Comment: If you're supposed to fill in $x=???$ then you get the Taylor series of $f$ at $x=0$ evaluated at $x=1$: $f(0)+f'(0)+f''(0)/2+\cdots$. This may or may not converge.

Comment: The chapter heading is: The Exponentials $e^t$ and $e^{at}$.  Pedro Tamaroff provided the same answer as the solutions manual.  Can you explain that in more detail please.

Comment: Strang is a wonderful resource, but don't expect a high level of rigor. Yes, as Pedro said, the Taylor series is $f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac12f''(0)x^2+\frac16f'''(0)x^3+\dots$. So plug in $x=1$. And, no, Strang means for you to apply $\left(e^{d/dx}\right)$ to $f(x)$, so $\left(e^{d/dx}\right)(f(x))$. This is mostly formal symbols.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the Taylor series at zero or MacLaurin series in a compact form as
$$
T_f(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}t^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\left(t\frac{d}{dx}\right)^kf\right)(0)}{k!}=\left(e^{t\frac{d}{dx}}f\right)(0)
$$
Exponentials of differential operators are seldom used in mathematics, but quite common in physics in quantum field theory.